# HostingEnviornment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem equivalent for Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asynchronous, azure-functions

I'm writing a custom logger that write logs from Azure Functions to a target over the network. This logger needs to be fire-and-forget asynchronous – it would be too slow to await each log write. However, I wouldn't want the last few log entries to be lost each time the host is shut down. Is there a way of registering my asynchronous operations for writing the logs using something equivalent to `HostingEnviornment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's currently nothing like `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` for Azure Functions (modern equivalents being `IApplicationLifetime` / `IHost`); Azure Functions does use these under the covers, but that level of configuration isn't available for end-user code. In the general case, there's Durable Functions, but that would be overkill to use just for logging.

Perhaps your logging system could use some work. I have an AF that streams its logs out to a compressed Azure blob. I flush it before returning the AF result, and I've been pleased with the performance so far.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I was thinking of using that approach too: keeping track of the asynchronous operations internally within the logger, and exposing a `FlushAsync` method to the consumer to be called just before the function completes. The implementation is slightly complicated since the logger, as a singleton, may be shared across multiple concurrent invocations of a function, and I'd only want a function to await the flushing of its last log entry, but it's doable.

Comment: Found a related request for adding a `FlushAsync` method to `ILogger` that captures this need: "There are points in a program logic where it is desirable to know that log events prior to that point have been committed before proceeding. This would involve doing a `Flush` of some sort and waiting for the `Flush` to complete. Currently `CloseAndFlush()` or `Dispose` can only really be called at the end of the application because both effectively tear down the existing logging pipeline. It would be great if there was a way to `Flush` at an intermediary point."

Comment: "Add a `Flush` method to `ILogger`. This would flush the pipeline and resolve when all pending writes are written. Since of course new writes may be introduced concurrently, the `Flush` represents a partial order for concurrent events, but should obey temporal causality for events written before the flush." [Flush an ILogger](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1111)